# Does Oracle update columns when the data values are the same?

Tags: oracle, sql-update

If I have a column called NAME and it has a value of "CLARK" and I run an update statement

```
update table1 set name = 'CLARK';
```

Does Oracle actually update the column or does it ignore the update command since the values are the same?

I found this question ([Oracle, how update statement works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670842/oracle-how-update-statement-works)) and the first answer implies that an update occurs even if the values are equal.  I also tried it in SQL Developer and it ran but I don't know if an update truly occurred.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Oracle does update the column even if it the same.

In a really simple example, this makes no difference.  But consider the following:-

- When a record is updated, a lock is obtained on that record for the updating session,
- When a record is updated, triggers on the table would fire

This aspects of the update show that the column is actually updated.

Of course, perhaps there are some optimisations when the value is the same, but these are not visible to you as a user of Oracle.

Comment: So if the update does occur then does that mean if auditing is being tracked (my understanding is that Oracle can track changes at the column level) then even if values don't change it will be considered an update and be tracked by the auditing?  Also, this means that if an "update" really doesn't "update" because the values are the same then this should be accounted for in code, right?  Like checking for equality and not updating if values are equal?

Comment: @BigFish I'm not sure what Oracle auditing does.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all row are updated and all triggers fired, even if the actual values doesn't change.